# Iterating through a 2D array with foreach

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, foreach

I was trying to iterate through an array with this statement: foreach(int[] arr in arr2D). It works similarly in Java. Why does it not work in C#? Thanks!

```
public static int[] RowSums(int[,] arr2D)
{
  int[] sums = new int[arr2D.Length];
  int rowCount = 0;

  foreach (int[] arr in arr2D)
  {
    sums[rowSums] = ArraySum(arr);
    rowSums++;
  } 

  return sums;
}
```

Comment: Need to see your code. But you might not initialize the second arrays with new int[]

Comment: Worth a read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I have posted the method I am using it in

Comment: I was thinking of using GetLength with nested for loops instead.

Comment: _Why does it not work in C#_ is not a proper problem description!

Comment: It's not a problem. It's a question. I also posted my code which explains what I tried to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int[,] is not an IEnumerable of int[], but of int. Therefore you cannot use it like that in the foreach-loop. Also, you must make use of the [Array.GetLength()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method to find out the number of elements in each row.

```
public static int[] RowSums(int[,] arr2D)
{
    int numRows = arr2D.GetLength(0);
    int numColumns = arr2D.GetLength(1);
    int[] sums = new int[numRows];

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numColumns; ++col)
        {
            sums[row] += arr2D[row, col];
        }
    }
    return sums;
}
```

Comment: I actually just typed out the same thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using a List<> object and Linq makes code trivial

```
        public static List<int> RowSums(List<List<int>> arr2D)
        {
            return arr2D.Select(x => x.Sum()).ToList();
        }​
```

Comment: The only reason I'm using arrays is because the exercise called for using them. I had to create a class called DiverseArray.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper way to approach the problem. You are currently using multidimensional array (`int[n,n]`) and these does not offer any methods to deal with rows nor columns (suppose you got 3-dimensional array -> what does a row mean?). If you want to iterate through values as rows you should use jagged arrays (`int[n][]`). Your code would become something similar to this:

```
public static int[] RowSums(int[][] arr2D)
    {
        //declare variables
        int[] sums = new int[arr2D.GetLength(0)];
        int rowSums = 0;

        //loop through array rows
        foreach (int[] arr in arr2D)
        {
            //accumulate row sum
            sums[rowSums] = ArraySum(arr);

            //update counter
            rowSums++;
        } //end foreach

        return sums;
    } //RowSums
```