# Loop through "an array in an array" in C#

Tags: c#

How would I go about looping through an array in an array. Something that looks a bit like this:

> `int[,]`

This is the thing I want to achieve:

```
int[,] obj

for(int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++) {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Multidimenional Array parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312603/) and [How do you loop through a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301109/) and [Iterate Multi-Dimensional Array with Nested Foreach Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893297/) and [How to use foreach with a two dimensional array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646580/) and [Iterating through a 2D array with foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559289/)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer! All you need is a foreach block. All you have to do is: `foreach (var item in itemArray) { }`